# IF: When not to use the subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I read there are two purposes of using the subjunctive mood. One of which is to describe an unreal or doubtful condition. Often in a clause beginning with the word "if."

My question is: are there times when we can use the subordinating conjunction "if" without using the subjunctive mood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You do this whenever the if statement is making statements or predictions about the current world

> If he goes outside, he will get wet.
>
> If it is raining today, yesterday's forecast was wrong.
>
> If she is happy, she won't fire you.

The subjunctive is only used when the if statement is speculating or making statements about how the world would be if things were different.

> If it were Thursday, we could go to the trivia night.
>
> If he were a woman, he could get in free.